# Calculating the commutator (derived) subgroup of $S_3$

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, derived-subgroup

How can I calculate it easily?

I showed that the commutator group of $S_3$ is generated by $(123)$ in $S_3$ using the fact that $S_3$ is isomorphic to $D_6$ and relation in $D_6$ but that was tedious

Are there any elegant methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The commutator subgroup can be characterised as being the smallest normal subgroup such that the quotient is abelian; by this I mean that if $N$ is normal in $G$ with $G/N$ abelian then $N$ contains the commutator subgroup.

The only normal subgroups of $S_3$ are $\{e\}$ and the $C_3$ subgroup generated by $(123)$ (being normal is a direct consequence of having index $2$).

The respective quotients have sizes $1$, $6$ and $2$ and since $S_3$ is nonabelian and a group of order $2$ must be, we can say that the commutator subgroup must be $C_3$.

Comment: That is truly beautiful. thanks for your help matt!

Comment: Note: $S_3$ is normal in itself.

Answer (score 7):

If $x$ and $y$ are in $S_3$, then their commutator, $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$, is an even permutation. So the commutator subgroup is a subgroup of $A_3$, which is just the identity and the 3-cycles.

Now since there are elements of $S_3$ that don't commute, the commutator subgroup isn't just the 1-element group, so it must be all of $A_3$.

Comment: The point about that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ is even permutation is awesome :) +1!

Answer (score -1):

Use the start of Myerson’s answer:  If x and y are in $S3$, then their commutator, $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ is an even permutation. So the commutator subgroup is a subgroup of $A3$, which is $ \{e,(123),(132)\} $

Then, it cannot be just $ \{e, (123) \}$ because while those two elements are commutative, that set is not closed, and thus not a subgroup.  One needs to include $(123)(123)= (132)$ to get a subgroup, and hence one gets all of $A3$.

Comment: Don't use mark-up. The site uses MathJax. [Here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/742).