# Is the commutator subgroup of a commutator subgroup itself?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a multiplicative group. The *commutator* of $a,b\in G$ is the element $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. (Now $a,b\in G$ commute iff their commutator is the identity.) The *commutator subgroup* of $G$, denoted $[G,G]$, is the subgroup generated by all commutators of all elements.

Example. If $G$ is abelian, then every commutator is the identity, so the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ is the trivial group.

(The commutator subgroup is used to construct the *abelianization* of $G$ as the quotient $G/[G,G]$, which I've encountered in learning homology.)

Now, an arbitrary element of $[G,G]$ need not be itself a commutator. So, is the commutator subgroup of $[G,G]$ again all of $[G,G]$? If not, is there an easy characterizations of groups $G$ for which the commutator subgroup of $[G,G]$ is again $[G,G]$?

Comment: You might be interested in [derived series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Derived_series) and [perfect group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A group for which $G=G'$ is called *perfect*. You might want to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group). All non-abelian simple groups belong to this category.

Comment: In particular, this answer led to an answer to my question (from the Wikipedia page on perfect groups): a group $G$ satisfying $G' = G''$ is called __quasi-perfect__, ie. its commutator subgroup $G'$ is perfect, ie. the commutator subgroup of the commutator subgroup is the commutator subgroup.

Comment: Yes that is correct, well done! Glad you learned something.

Answer (score 9):

Let $G=S_3$. Then $[G,G]=A_3$ (see answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1418212/commutator-derived-subgroup-of-s3)) which is Abelian so $[A_3,A_3]=\langle e\rangle\ne[G,G]$.

Answer (score 5):

The commutator subgroup is often called the *derived subgroup* and denoted $G'$. This makes it easy to write its derived subgroup as $G''$. An example of a group with $G''\ne G'$ is $G=A_4$.

If instead we consider groups of upper triangular matrices over a finite
field, we can get sequences $G\supset G'\supset G''\supset\cdots$
which finally stabilise after any given finite number of steps.